# Looking for guidance on cyclic group theory (Abstract Algebra)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here's the theorem I'm attempting to prove: Let $G = \langle g \rangle$ be a cyclic group and $H$ a non-trivial subgroup of G.  Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $g^m \in H$.  Show that $H\subseteq \langle g^m\rangle$.

Here's what I have set up so far:
Let $h \in H$ so that $h = g^k$ for some $k \in Z$.  We must show that $m | k$.

I vaguely understand the path I need to take in order to prove this theorem. I have the exponent $k$ such that $k = m * x + r$ for some $m,x \in Z$ and $(0 \leq r < m)$.  Then, I need to show that $r$ must be $0$, otherwise $h$ can't be in $H$.

How can I best put these pieces together into a proof using this abstract format?  I've used concrete examples to prove the theorem, but I'm having trouble translating it into 'proof language'.  Thanks in advance for any guidance that can be provided!

Comment: Try using the closure property.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for your definition of $h,k,m,x,r$ you have
$$
h = g^k = g^{mx+r} = (g^m)^x g^r
$$
and left multiplying this equation by $((g^m)^x)^{-1}$ we see
$$
g^r = ((g^m)^x)^{-1} h.
$$
Can you prove that the right hand side is a product of elements of $H$?  If so, do you see how this will imply that $r = 0$?

Comment: I think I see the implication, but to clarify, if $r$ = 0, then $g^r$ = 1, thus making the right hand side a divisor of k?

Comment: You might have it right although you may also be mixing references to integers and references to elements of the group, if $r = 0$ then the right hand side of the first equation above expresses $h$ as an element of $\langle g^m \rangle$.  It's the fact that $k = mx$ turns out to be multiple of $m$ (not of $k$) that matters.